# Pushing docker image in AWS ECR from SageMaker Studio using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

We can now publish Docker images to AWS ECR directly from **SageMaker Studio** using this code https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli
I did follow the easy installation instructions:

```
!pip install sagemaker-studio-image-build
sm-docker build .
```

Also Trust policy and permissions have been set as described in the instructions.
But I'm getting the error "**Command did not exit successfully docker push**" at the stage where it is pushing the Docker image to AWS ECR. Any idea why? Here are the details print as output:

```
[Container] 2021/05/04 06:57:20 Running command echo Pushing the Docker image...
Pushing the Docker image...

[Container] 2021/05/04 06:57:20 Running command docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
The push refers to repository [752731038471.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-studio-d-tfbogtriaiml]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: 752731038471.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-studio-d-tfbogtriaiml

[Container] 2021/05/04 06:57:20 Command did not exit successfully docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG exit status 1
[Container] 2021/05/04 06:57:20 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/05/04 06:57:20 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG. Reason: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dockerfile, there was a reference to another file that was not present in the directory from where the command `sm-docker build .` was launched.